# Why is cmake find_package(Vulkan) not outputting any environment variable?

Tags: cmake, vulkan

I'm learning Vulkan and trying to use Cmake for the configuration. While cmake finds Vulkan, it does not output any variable. Why is that?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(VulkanTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
# Alright, no errors? Tell me what you found!
message("Vulkan found? " ${VULKAN_FOUND})
message("Alright, where is it? " ${VULKAN_LIBRARY})
message("And I can include it? " ${VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Output:

```
Vulkan found? TRUE
Alright, where is it?
And I can include it?
```

I tried changing variable names for `Vulkan_LIBRARY` and others and I tried checking other outputs described here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindVulkan.html, but I can't make it show the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Spelling and case probably matter.  This version works for me:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(VulkanTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
# Alright, no errors? Tell me what you found!
message("Vulkan found? " ${VULKAN_FOUND})
message("Alright, where is it? " ${Vulkan_LIBRARIES})
message("And I can include it? " ${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I don't know why `VULKAN_FOUND` works since the document you referenced says it should be `Vulkan_FOUND`.  There's probably an explanation deep in the CMake docs someplace.

Comment: I don't know if I've been clear. I've changed the spelling and it does not work either. `Vulkan_FOUND` is the same as `VULKAN_FOUND`.

Comment: Yes, but `Vulkan_LIBRARIES` isn't the same as `Vulkan_LIBRARY`.  Your original code used `VULKAN_LIBRARY` and I can't tell from your comment if you changed its spelling or not.  The correct name is `Vulkan_LIBRARIES`, which works for me as I showed above.  And for me (on Windows), these are case sensitive.  `Vulkan_LIBRARIES` and `Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS` both work, but `VULKAN_LIBRARIES` and `VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIRS` do not.  Check if your Vulkan SDK is installed correctly.  If on Linux, you may need to install the SDK tarball (See the hint at the bottom of the FindVulkan.html doc)